# Trying to inject two repositories with generic implementation is failing

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection, javabeans

I am trying to code implementation for two models classes using generic.

I have two model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SMS_INFO")
public class SmsInfo
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = Constants.ID_COLUMN)
    private Long smsInfoId;

    // other fields and public getters
}
```

Similar model class is there for EmailInfo.

Now, for this two classes I am trying to create generic repository and service classes as follows:

```
public interface InfoRepository <Info> extends JpaRepository<Info, Long> {}

public interface CommunicationInfoServiceI <Info>
{
    // Some abstract methods
}

@Named
public class CommunicationInfoServiceImpl<Info> implements CommunicationInfoServiceI<Info>
{
    @Inject
    private InfoRepository<Info> infoRepository;

    // Other implementations
}
```

Now, I am trying to inject the two services as follows:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class ServiceFactory
{
    @Inject
    private CommunicationInfoServiceI<SmsInfo> smsInfoService;

    @Inject
    private CommunicationInfoServiceI<EmailInfo> emailInfoService;

    // Other Getter methods
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceFactory': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private CommunicationInfoServiceI ServiceFactory.smsInfoService; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'communicationInfoServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private InfoRepository CommunicationInfoServiceImpl.infoRepository; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

Can anybody please help me, I am stuck over here?

Thanks in advance.

> Note: I have tried removing all injections of generic classes and left
>   InfoRepository as it is, it is still giving the same error. I think it
>   shouldn't be because of serviceFactory, it should be something to do
>   with JPARepository, initially it might be trying to inject it and
>   failing in doing, as JVM might not be knowing about 'Info' type. Can
>   we do something for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Guice for injections you should bind you interface to implementation class in Module configuration. If you use spring context, you should define your repository bean in spring config.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating one more common parent model class to smsInfo and emailInfo as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class CommunicationInfo
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = Constants.ID_COLUMN)
    protected Long id;
}
```

and extended it from both the classes SmsInfo and EmailInfo.

After that I have to use extend in repository as well for the generic type as follows:

```
public interface CommunicationInfoRepository <Info extends CommunicationInfo> extends JpaRepository<Info, Long>
{

}
```

using it same way at other places as well.

Thanks everyone for responding.